# Oracle Format Models Million / Billion

Tags: oracle, numeric, notation

I am looking to take a number, and truncate / round it and display it with a notation indicator like this:

10000000 --> 10M
1000000045.76 --> 100B

If < 1 Million, just leave it as is.  If >= 1 Million, display the M / B / T notation.   Does Oracle have a format model for this?

Comment: i dont think so there is million, Billion notation available in Oracle(Atleast I am not aware). You have to do it using case statement

Comment: here's all the formats - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr07.htm#CHDJBGCJ . what you want does not exist built in.  Write a small function to do the conversion.